# Counting specific element line by line

Tags: perl

I would like to count number of occurrence of `NN` in each line and then remove lines containing with more occurrences of `NN`. I wrote a script to count the occurrence line by line, but its not giving the desired output.

#### Input:

```
Qcode   B_32_ISO.GT     B_45_ISO.GT     B_63_ISO.GT     B_72_ISO.GT     B_85_ISO.GT     B_89_ISO.GT     B_9_I
NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN
```

#### Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open( In,  "$ARGV[0]" );
open( Out, ">$ARGV[1]" );

%count;

while ( $line = <In> ) {

    chomp( $line );

    if ( $line =~ /rs#/ ) {
        print Out "$line\n";
        next;
    }

    @arr = split( /\t/, $line );

    for ( $i = 11; $i <= $#arr; $i++ ) {
        $count{ $arr[$i] }++;
    }

    while ( my ( $key, $value ) = each( %count ) ) {
        print "$key:$value\n";
    }
}

close In;
close Out;
```

#### Output :

```
TT:2
NN:538
AC:2
AA:6

TT:2
NN:1070
AC:2
CC:6
AA:6
TT:3
CT:1
```

I want to count the occurrence in each line instead of summing for all lines.

Comment: Your data appears to contain no tab characters. If I change to `split ' ', $line` (which splits on any amount of any white space) then I see `NN:3` on stdout. That makes sense, because the second line of data contains `NN` 14 times; your loop starts at 11, and 14 - 11 is 3. Nothing is ever written to your `Out` file handle because no lines contain `rs#`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't clear %count before moving to a next line.

Why don't you use [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) and [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings)? Using `%count;` on line 6 does nothing, it's cleaner to limit its scope to the loop only - so you don't even need to clear it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please post short code here.

Comment: Use `%count = ();` to clear the hash. Use `use strict; use warnings;` to turn on strict and warnings.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

This counts the number of `NN`s on a line and skips lines that contain `NN`s:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if (my $number_of_nn = (() = $line =~ /(NN)/g)) {
        print "Number of NN is $number_of_nn\n";
    }
    else {
        print $line;
    }
}

__DATA__
Qcode   B_32_ISO.GT     B_45_ISO.GT     B_63_ISO.GT     B_72_ISO.GT     B_85_ISO.GT     B_89_ISO.GT     B_9_I
NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN      NN
```

Comment: That is very clumsy. It will count a single entry of `NNN` as one, and `NNNN` as two. It is also counter-productive to use the arcane `$scalar = () =` when a temporary array variable would make things much clearer. You should rely on the compiler to optimise unless you need special performance. Over all, `my $num_nn = grep /NN/, split ' ', $line` is much more appropriate.